# copy-paste between Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to copy and paste data between 2 Google Sheets spreadsheets: in spreadsheet 1 I have a shared planner of 10 people, where each marks in his sheet personal commitments divided between morning and afternoon for each day. There are also two spaces M and P where everyone manually marks commitments with me.

In spreadsheet 2 I have the small jobs assigned to each of them with a summary line that tells me if they are free (they can do up to 3 jobs M and P).

I would like to copy the data in this row in the M and P columns in the sheet of each of them.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but what's wrong with `CTLR - C` and `CTRL - V` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to copy and paste data, you could use `CTRL + C` `CTRL + V` as suggested by @Jeremy Thille.

If you want to reference data from another sheet, you can do it this way : `=NameOfYourSheet!A1`, or `='Name Of Your Sheet'!A1` if the name contains spaces.

If the data is on a different spreadsheet, you have to use `IMPORTRANGE` function. Take a look at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340.

Not sure about the `javascript` tag, `google-sheets` would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was not able to explain it and so I send you an image of files.

I have to copy the row "Peter" in Sheet 2 and paste in sheet 1 following the date and  sharing of M (morning) and P (afternoon). In suggested way it is too long, and so I thought to GS.
In image2 you find the result I would like to have

[image]

Meanwhile I find a formula that I put in Peter tab, cell marked M and P (1/10) and works very well
in B4 =transpose(query({Planning!A3:DT3};"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ";text(query(transpose({column(Planning!C3:BL3);mod(column(Planning!C3:BL3)-column(Planning!C3);2)});"Select Col1 where Col2=0");"Col0")))))

in C4 =transpose(query({Planning!A3:DT3};"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ";text(query(transpose({column(Planning!D3:BL3);mod(column(Planning!D3:BL3)-column(Planning!D3);2)});"Select Col1 where Col2=0");"Col0")))))

I have 25 people tabs with six month planning. At the end ok week I delete the related data.
How can I make automatic the work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I find a formula that I put in Peter tab, cell marked M and P (1/10) and works very well in B4 =transpose(query({Planning!A3:DT3};"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ";text(query(transpose({column(Planning!C3:BL3);mod(column(Planning!C3:BL3)-column(Planning!C3);2)});"Select Col1 where Col2=0");"Col0")))))

in C4 =transpose(query({Planning!A3:DT3};"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ";text(query(transpose({column(Planning!D3:BL3);mod(column(Planning!D3:BL3)-column(Planning!D3);2)});"Select Col1 where Col2=0");"Col0")))))

I have 25 people tabs with six month planning. At the end ok week I delete the related data. How can I make automatic the work?

Comment: The answer should not contain additional questions. Moreover, it looks like the same content is contained in your previous answer. Please delete